# Android Gradle 1.1 - adding a test dependency on another project's tests

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 modules: *A* and *B*.

-*A* is a standalone module. Its tests run just fine all by itself.
-*B* is a dependent module. Its tests require a certain file in *A*'s test folder (one test file in *B* extends one in *A*)

Here are what I believe to be the relevant parts of *B*'s `build.gradle`:

```
android { 
  ...
  sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += "../A/src/test/java"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':A')

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
}
```

While this technically works for what I need it - it has the nasty side effect that whenever I run *A*'s unit tests, they also run all of *B*'s tests. I would really like if this was not the case.

I am using Android Gradle 1.1 (along with Android Studio 1.1), and I think this is causing me some issues. I have tried all the solutions I could find - unfortunately, none of them seem to apply for Android Gradle 1.1 - for example:

Removing the `sourceSets` from *B*'s `build.gradle` and adding (to *B*'s dependencies) the line

```
 testCompile project(':A').sourceSets.test.output
```

Produces the build error `Could not find property 'test' on SourceSet container.`

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easier/better way to include test files across modules? I'm pretty new to Gradle/Android Studio, so it's totally possible I'm missing a dead obvious solution.

Comment: Adding A's test to B's sourcesets => running A tests causes B tests to run? That doesn't make sense in my head, Is this still the case? BTW, an alternative way is to package A's tests as a jar and use that as B's testCompile dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your modules by tree using command:

```
gradle projects
```

It will list all your project modules and you can see if you are configuring your sub projects in a right way. Also run command:

```
gradle --gui
```

It will list all the tasks for all modules, and you can always run one module independently from other e.g.

```
gradle A:tasks
gradle A:test
gradle B:test
```

OR both

```
gradle A:tasks B:test
```

Note: You do not need to specify the A if it is the root project and B,C,D sub-modules but for submodules you need to specify it. When you do:

```
gradle --gui
```

You can double click on any task to see how it runs and you can do the same manually from command line. Hope this helps